# Python packaging with pyproject.toml and setuptools

Tags: python, command-line-interface, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

## What I am trying to achieve

My goal is, after installing the python package, to be able to run a command without having to type `python` before the command.

### Example

```
$ excommand
Hello, World!
```

### Directory Structure

```
.
├── example
    ├── __init__.py
    └── exmodule.py
├── .venv
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.cfg
```

exmodule.py

```py
def command():
    print("Hello, World!")
```

pyproject.toml

```ini
[build-system]
requires = [ "setuptools" ]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = Example
version = 1.0.0

[options]
packages = find:

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts = 
    excommand = example.exmodule:command
```

## The Problem

After the execution of the following command on terminal:

```
$ python3 -m build --wheel
```

No warnings or errors are printed to the terminal but the command does not work:

```
$ excommand
zsh: command not found: excommand
```

## What was tried

Before using the TOML file, I was just using the `setup.cfg` file with a `setup.py`, but when installing the package with the command `pip install .` I was warned that future versions of pip would guarantee the use of TOML files. It was not working either, so tried using TOML.

Comment: It looks like you're building a wheel file distribution for your package, but have you also _installed_ it? Have you tried `pip install .`?

Comment: So, should i run `python3 -m build --wheel` and `pip install .`?

Comment: AFAIK, `python3 -m build --wheel` is only need to build a distribution file. You don't need to run it prior to attempting to install your package, since pip is just going to re-build it from the source tree and your `pyproject.toml` anyway

Comment: Could you answer my question with your comments so I can accept it?

Comment: not sure what I'm doing wrong but I have your setup and the build/dist dir is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With newer setuptools and pyproject.toml you can use:
(only relevant parts included)

```ini
[build-system]
build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'
requires = ["setuptools>=69.2.0", "setuptools-scm"]

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["yourpackage"]

[project.scripts]
yourbinary = "yourpackage.yourpackage:main"
```

You must create a `main()` function in your yourpackage.yourpackage.py:

```py
#<all your fantastic code>

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='superdupermain')
    parser.add_argument('--debug', help='debug', action='store_true')
    :

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

When you run `pip install yourpackage` in a `<venv>` it will install:

```
    <venv>\lib\site-packages\yourpackage\yourpackage.py
    <venv>\scripts\yourbinary.exe
```

It will be in your path so you can execute `yourbinary.exe`
for linux it will be an executable `yourbinary`